# Conductive materials quality

Tags: print-material, material, multi-material

I was considering the possibility to 3D print some capacitors with various forms and shapes in order to test them. I need to be able to print both the non-conductive and the conductive materials at the same time so I have the following questions:

1. I suppose that since I need to do multi-material printing, i will have to stick with FDM. Is that correct?
2. I have seen that there are some PLA materials that are mixed with dust of metals and become conductive themselves. Do they become also capacitive? Are there any better options for a conductive material in a multi-material scenario?

Comment: This might be a better fit over on EE.SE; Someone can likely answer the printability questions here, but the capacitive properties of the materials is a little beyond the average "maker".

Comment: Even if you succeed in printing without any shorts, you are going to have horrible reproducibility problems.  Further, I doubt most PLA/ABS/whatever materials have a dielectric constant of any useable value.

Comment: There is Proto-Pasta's Conductive filament... no experience with it but you should use a 2-extruder setup, which contains "conductive carbon black", a form of very finely powdered graphite. https://www.proto-pasta.com/pages/conductive-pla

Comment: in the end i bought the Proto pasta conductive filament, and measured it. resistivity is what is advertised (3KOhm/10cm). The filament has also capacitance. i printed 2 sheets 2cmx2cmx1mm and whith a piece of paper in between i measured 0.1nF

Answer (score 1):

Someone has already studied this: [study of electrical properties of 3D printed materials](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://radio.feld.cvut.cz/conf/poster/proceedings/Poster_2018/Section_PE/PE_043_Vesely.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiInPybkJHnAhWQiOAKHUhHDk0QFjABegQIDxAK&usg=AOvVaw29WgLT3hfP1cPnHeiKtL7y).

ABS: dielectric constant about 3.
PLA: 2.7-2.9.